# PHP - SDK - Facebook - Fan Page get the following data

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

have a question.

PHP SDK - facebook

How can I get the following data
FanPage Name -
FanPage ID -
FanPage Token access -

of fanpages that I manage?

## I tried using

`

```
// Get the current access token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
echo "Sobre Fan Pages: ";
print_r($accounts);

foreach ($accounts as $pub) {
foreach ($pub['data'] as $page) {
echo 'Pages: '.$page['name'].' '.$page['access_token'].' '.$page['id']."<br/>";
```

}
   }

`
But $accounts only returns user data nothing about fanpages

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get a token that grants 'manage_pages' permissions. Look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/  (search the page for 'accounts' )

You need to redirect the user to a new login using the php sdk getLoginUrl($params) function, and specify as $params['scope'] a comma separated list of the permission you are requesting. Make sure manage_page is there.
Then you get a new token that you can use to retrive the pages with /me/accounts.

HTH